# Create in a textbox excel with java

Tags: java, apache-poi

i have a **document** excel with **textboxes** 
i want to create in this textboxes a text from java code 
 this is the code to get value , how i'm going to edit it using poid apache

```
    try {
     FileInputStream fsIP = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Book1.xls"));

     //   InputStream input = new FileInputStream("Book1.xls");
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(fsIP);
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFPatriarch pat = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch();
        List children = pat.getChildren();

        Iterator it = children.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            HSSFShape shape = (HSSFShape) it.next();
            if (shape instanceof HSSFTextbox) {

                shape.getAnchor()
                HSSFTextbox textbox = (HSSFTextbox) shape;
                HSSFRichTextString richString = textbox.getString();
                String str = richString.getString();
                System.out.println("String: " + str);
                System.out.println("String length: " + str.length());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This link might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967168/obtain-textbox-value-from-excel-in-java

Comment: this is for read i wanna create

Comment: This might be useful: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSimpleShape.html#setString(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.RichTextString)