# Obtain textbox value from Excel in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd

I have an Excel file (data.xlsx) with [the following pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYsW2.png) and I need to read a value from a textbox inside that Excel file.

I am currently using pandas library and I tried to obtain the value, but unfortunately could not find any API for that objective.

Does anyone know how could this be done?

**More info**:

My question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967168/obtain-textbox-value-from-excel-in-java) sister question from Java.

**Edit**:

**I have provided a solution** for anyone who wonders how to search for shapes (and possibly all other items) in an excel file, manually (that is, without external modules from pip). It's actually pretty simple. See my comment.

Comment: Put that code that you DID try and perhaps we can assist in fixing it.

Comment: I tried Googling around but nothing came up regarding Excel textboxes, so there was no code that I actually tried. I'm asking here to see if it's even possible in Python. Thanks!

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow should always come with code. Just asking whether something is possible or not is not in the spirit of the platform.

Comment: I disagree. [Example with 2000 upvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository?rq=1), [example with 1000 upvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp?rq=1). I think you're just being pricks. But it doesn't matter, I solved this on my own. I even shared the solution for everyone to benefit. I think that's a bit more in the spirit of the platform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for **all the kind help**, but I worked this out on my own.

I got this to work using *zipfile module*. Apparently, [Excel is actually a suite that works on compressed XML files (changing the *.xlsx to *.zip reveals the contents of the file) when saving and reading from *.xlsx](http://www.excel-exercise.com/xls-xlsx-file/), so I could easily search the text needed with the comfort of XML.

Here's the module I made. By calling `Sheet('path/to/sheet.xlsx').shapes.text`, you can now easily find the text inside textboxes:

```
import zipfile as z


class Sheet(str):
    @property
    def shapes(this):
        s = z.ZipFile(this)
        p='xl/drawings/drawing1.xml'  # shapes path, *.xlsx default
        p='drs/shapexml.xml'  # shapes path, *.xls default
        return XML(s.read(p))


class XML(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = str(value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.value)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.value[i]

    def tag_content(self, tag):
        return [XML(i) for i in self.value.split(tag)[1::2]]

    @property
    def text(self):
        t = self.tag_content('xdr:txBody')  # list of XML codes, each containing a seperate textboxes, messy (with extra xml that is)
        l = [i.tag_content('a:p>') for i in t]  # split into sublists by line breaks (inside the textbox), messy
        w = [[[h[1:-2] for h in i.tag_content('a:t')] if i else ['\n'] for i in j] for j in l]  # clean into sublists by cell-by-cell basis (and mind empty lines)
        l = [[''.join(i) for i in j] for j in w]  #  join lines overlapping multiple cells into one sublist
        return ['\n'.join(j) for j in l]  #  join sublists of lines into strings seperated by newline char
```

So now the pattern provided in my question will be output as `['comments extra']`, while a pattern such as:

1. > This 
   >   is
   >
   > Text 
   >   in 
   >   a
   >   textbox
   >   on
   >
   > a 
   >   sheet
2. > And this
   >   is another text box somewhere else
   >
   > Regardless of the overlapped cells

Will be output as `['This is\nText in a textbox on\na sheet','And this is another text box somewhere else\nRegardless of the overlapped cells']`.

***You're welcome.***

Comment: While this will work for you in this particular instance, it is not a general solution. And rather than rolling your own XML parser it would be better to use one from the standard library.

Comment: Still happy if any general solution comes up!

Comment: i'm so glad to found your answer.... `changing the *.xlsx to *.zip reveals the contents of the file`  thanks for this sentence

Answer (score 2):

You can use Dispatch:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename = 'your file name/path')
ws = wb.Worksheets(sheet_index)
```

Where **sheet_index** is whatever number corresponds to the sheet of interest in the workbook. ws.Shapes will have all of the shape objects on the sheet. You can access a shape (textbox) with an integer **index**, Shapes(index), and then check the name of the object with its name property Shapes(index).Name.

```
ws.Shapes(index).Name
```

Once you figure out which shape you want, then you can view its text like this:

```
ws.Shapes(index).Characters().Text
```

Note that you have to *call* () the Characters method.
To assign text, simply assign it. Or you could replace parts of it as well (like dates) with the standard replace method.

```
ws.Shapes(index).Characters().Text = 'Beluga Whales'

ws.Shapes(index).TextFrame.Characters().Text = ws.Shapes(index).TextFrame.Characters().Text.replace('original text', 'new text')
```

Comment: This works for me until the `ws.Shapes(1).Characters().Text` line.  That returns `AttributeError: <unknown>.Characters`  The rest of it, `ws.Shapes(1)`, is a `<COMObject <unknown>>`

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible with openpyxl (version 2.4)

Comment: Thanks, I have shared a solution without openpyxl or any other external pip modules.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this to get value from text box.

```
    xls = ExcelFile(request.FILES['yourFileName'])
    df = xls.parse(xls.sheet_names[0])
    for i in df.values:
        print(i[0])               #here you get the value from text box
```

thanks

Comment: This code is incomplete (it looks like it's using Pandas) but also does not do what was asked.