# How to insert / read Mathematical equation in excelsheet cell through java program

Tags: java

How to insert / read Mathematical equation in excelsheet cell through java program or any other Framework.we need to add mathmatical equation in excelsheet and upload into database

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47219155 - are you part of the same class, your questions are extremely similar and equally low quality.

Comment: You can use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) to manipulate Excel files with Java.

Comment: Your question is partculary unclear and need way more context to give a chance of anyone to answer

Answer (score 1):

Library from apache apache.poi.hssf can parse excel workbook and can return equations from any cell

```
Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
String formula = cell.getCellFormula();
```

in formula string you have full excel formula

Comment: We need library of Mathematical equation to read from excelsheet cell not Formuale. Example: squareroot of x.

Comment: Explain what you mean mathematical equations. In excel is with
=SUM(B1:B20) or only text cell?

Comment: Mathematical equation in excel by click on insert tab -- select Equation icon. Choose any equation which displays on excel..we need to read mathematical equation and inserts into database.

Comment: Equation in excel is textbox.
You can read textboxes through apache poi too.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967168/obtain-textbox-value-from-excel-in-java answer how you can read textboxes